# Calligraphic font for Bitstream font and inter-package error

Tags: fonts, math-mode, siunitx

I try to load and use a calligraphic font but it seems that the combination of siunitx, upgreek and bm causes the error, but for some reasons the error-message ('Too many math alphabets used in version normal. $\mathcal{F}') doesn't appear when I exclude on of the packages. How can I solve the problem? (I already played with the order of the packages but with no result, thx)

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}


\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 



 %{XCharter} - Font
 \usepackage[scaled=.98,sups,lf]{XCharter} % osf for text, not math 
 \usepackage{cabin} % sans serif
 \usepackage[varqu,varl]{zi4} % sans serif typewriter
 \usepackage[libertine,bigdelims,vvarbb,scaled=1.03]{newtxmath} % bb from STIX
 \usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa} % mathcal
\linespread{1.04}
\usepackage[scale]{tgheros}
\usepackage{soul}


\usepackage{upgreek} 
\usepackage[per=slash,decimalsymbol=comma,loctolang={DE:ngerman}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{bm}


\begin{document}
$\mathcal{F}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: `newtxmath` with all those options is *very* hungry of math families. Do you need those calligraphic letters also in the argument of `\bm`? What's `upgreek` for?

Comment: Which fonts are you actually trying to use? Right now you are loading several font packages and many of them are overriding the settings of the previous ones (for text), and overriding/adding to specifications of font families (for maths). You can have no more than 16 alphabets for maths, I think, and you are presumably exceeding that. But, more generally, you are creating a recipe for confusion and nasty surprises. tldr: you need to sort out your fonts ;).

Comment: `\usepackage{cabin}` currently has no effect. It is overridden by `tgheros`. This isn't the problem (which is as egreg explained) but it is confusing. Also, the call to `XCharter` will give you *lining* figures - not oldstyle.

Comment: I trying to use Xcharter as text-font and the math-font as recommended by the XCharter manual. (Personally, I don't like the  old style lining figures that's the reason I use the standard option (lf)).  Either way, bm is used to indicate matrices and upgreek provides non-italic greek letters for the text mode.

Comment: Well, I don't think that I'll combine bm with the calligraphic letter. (At the moment it's only used to refer to the Fourier- and Lapace-transformation). Does this mean that there is a solution?

Comment: I don't understand your comment about upgreek being for text mode, it is a purely math font package (and eating into the upper limit of 16 math fonts)

Comment: Upgreek is necessary to provide upright greek characters, upright letters are necessary to indicate mathematical constants (and to distinguish them from physical constant, e.g. euler's number vs.  elementaire lading)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are loading far too many fonts given that TeX only allows 16 math fonts, but anyway your example runs without error if you give `bm` a hint that that is what you are doing

```
\chardef\bmmax=2
\usepackage{bm}
```

Tells `bm` to be more conservative in its font usage.